# Is exponentiate a valid verb tense of exponentiation?

Tags: verbs, tenses

'Exponentiate' seems to fail spell checks and it doesn't appear to be valid in any official dictionaries that I can see. Though I do I see it used from time to time and see it in questionable "wiki" type online dictionaries.

I am interested to know if 'exponentiate' is a valid verb tense and perhaps just not yet codified - or if there's a grammatical (or semantic) reason that makes it invalid.

Just curious!

Comment: I abominate that people think they have to find a perfectly obvious word in one or another dictionary before they are allowed to use it.

Comment: Agreed - i’m interested as to why it fails spell check in the browser.

Comment: Interestingly ‘abominate’ surfaces in Mirriam Webster online - where ‘exponentiate’ doesn’t.

Comment: You will have to ask whoever wrote the software you're referencing what's wrong with it.

Comment: and Merriam-Webster?

Comment: There has never been a dictionary that contains “all the words” in a language. It just is not possible. Any expectation to the contrary is divorced from reality.

Comment: And heaven preserve us from spell checkers!

Comment: @lys - "I’m interested as to why it fails spell check in the browser" spell checkers in browsers, and famous office software are only as good as the dictionaries that they contain, and some are not very good (i.e. incomplete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the *Oxford English Dictionary* is behind a paywall, I can't blame you for not surfacing this:

> **exponentiate**, *v.*
>
> *Mathematics.*
>
> **1.** *intransitive*. To increase exponentially; also, more generally, to exhibit specified asymptotic behaviour as some limit is
> approached.
>
> **2.** *transitive*. To raise *e* or some other base (BASE *n.*<sup>1</sup> 20) to the power of; to subject to exponentiation. Also *absol.*
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Here are a couple of usage examples supplied . . .

Intransitive:

> <sub>1971   *Physical Rev.* D. **3** 970   We find that the
> leading Regge-pole term arising from single-ladder-exchange
> exponentiates.</sub>

Transitive:

> <sub>1978   *Physics Lett.* A. **64** 477/2   By solving the
> operator equations in their full nonlinear form..we are able to
> exponentiate the logarithmic terms into power law singularities.</sub>

Go forth and exponentiate.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. Can you confirm whether it fails a spellcheck for you in the browser?

Comment: When I type *exponentiate* into this box, I get a red underline for a spelling error.

Comment: Exactly! I wonder why..

Comment: In my experience as a mathematician, "exponentiate" is quite common in the transitive sense but not in the intransitive sense.

Comment: I don't get an error for exponentiate in Google Chrome except if the language is 'English (United States)'. If I set the language to just 'English' the word is not underlined.